# angularjs http post image file to drf rest interface got error: AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: angularjs, ajax, image, upload, django-rest-framework

I am creating a system consisting angularjs frontend web app and DRF rest interface.
I can use command line 'curl' to upload image file to DRF rest interface, but when I use angularjs http post, I got the error message: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'pk'

My DRF setup is as follows:

```
models.py:
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'post_image/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.author.id, filename)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False, editable=False, related_name='images')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, blank=False, editable=False, related_name='images')

    image = models.ImageField(_('image'), blank=True, null=True, upload_to=upload_to)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.updated = timezone.now()
        return super(PostImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


serializers.py
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='author-detail')
    post = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='post-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('url', 'image', 'author', 'post', 'created', 'updated')

views.py
class PostImageView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List and Create post image endpoint
    Allowed request method: Get, Post
    """
    serializer_class = PostImageSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostImageView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(post__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if 'upload' in self.request.data:
            file_obj = self.request.data['upload']
            serializer.save(author=self.request.user, post=post, image=file_obj)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


I am using JWT authentication:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ) ,
}
```

---

**Log error message:**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/post/22/image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 452, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 244, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 466, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 215, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 435, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 264, in to_representation
    return self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "/root/rest_drf/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 199, in get_url
    if obj.pk is None:
AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'pk'
[pid: 29484|app: 0|req: 2/4] 76.114.185.25 () {54 vars in 1242 bytes} [Sun Jan 24 16:41:13 2016] POST /api/v1/post/22/image => generated 107983 bytes in 153 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 92 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
```